# How to remove chunks from mongodb shard

Tags: mongodb, sharding, chunks

I have a collection where the sharding key is UUID (hexidecimal string). The collection is huge: 812 millions of documents, about 9600 chunks on 2 shards. For some reason I initially stored documents which instead of UUID had integer in sharding key field. Later I deleted them completely, and now all of my documents are sharded by UUID. But I am now facing a problem with chunk distribution. While I had documents with integer instead of UUID, balancer created about 2700 chunks for these documents, and left all of them on one shard. When I deleted all these documents, chunks were not deleted, they stayed empty and they will always be empty because I only use UUID now. Since balancer distrubutes chunks relying on chunk count per shard, not document count or size, one of my shards takes 3 times more disk space than another:

```
--- Sharding Status ---
db.click chunks:
    set1    4863
    set2    4784    // 2717 of them are empty

set1> db.click.count()
191488373

set2> db.click.count()
621237120
```

The sad thing here is mongodb does not provide commands to remove or merge chunks manually. 
My main question is, whould anything of this work to get rid of empty chunks:

1. Stop the balancer. Connect to each config server, remove from `config.chunks` ranges of empty chunks and also fix `minKey` slice to end at beginning of first non-empty chunk. Start the balancer.
   Seems risky, but as far as I see, `config.chunks` is the only place where chunk information is stored.
2. Stop the balancer. Start a new mongod instance and connect it as a 3rd shard. Manually move all empty chunks to this new shard, then shut it down forever. Start the balancer.
   Not sure, but as long as I dont use integer values in sharding key again, all queries should run fine.

Answer (score 0):

Some might read this and think that the empty chunks are occupying space. That's not the case - chunks themselves take up no space - they are logical ranges of shard keys.

However, chunk balancing across shards is based on the number of chunks, not the size of each chunk.

You might want to add your voice to this ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2487

Answer (score 0):

Since the mongodb balancer only balances chunks number across shards, having too many empty chunks in a collection can cause shards to be balanced by chunk number but severely unbalanced by data size per shard (e.g., as shown by db.myCollection.getShardDistribution()).

You need to identify the empty chunks, and merge them into chunks that have data.  This will eliminate the empty chunks.  This is all now documented in Mongodb docs (at least 3.2 and above, maybe even prior to that).